Linux not booting up/not showing any gui
When ever I try to boot up Linux it does not show any GUI. all it shows is some acpi bios errors like this https://i.sstatic.net/OLMhD.jpg. I can still go into the virtual terminals and my files seem to be intact.


I made this question after this same thing happened to me twice. I found out a good way to test what happened and how you can fix it.

test if it is a problem with the drivers.
sometimes if you have the wrong drivers installed the GUI will not boot. here is how to install new drivers to test out.(note this is for nvidia drivers)

try to get into tty2 by pressing alt and f2. it should show a login prompt. just put in your username and then your password.
now you need to remove the old drivers that may be causing the problem. to do this type in sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-driver-* this will remove all nvidia drivers
then you need to check what drivers are available for your system. type in sudo ubuntu-drivers list to see what drivers to install the out put should be like this


nvidia-driver-470
nvidia-driver-470-server
nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-535-open
nvidia-driver-535-server
nvidia-driver-535-server-open
nvidia-driver-550
nvidia-driver-550-open
nvidia-driver-550-server
nvidia-driver-550-server-open


now install a driver. I would recommend the latest driver as that is what works most of the time. in this case the latest driver is nvidia-driver-550 so to install it type sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:550
restart your system by typing reboot

if that does not work, your desktop environment may have been removed.
how to reinstall gnome

try to get into tty2 by pressing alt and f2. it should show a login prompt. just put in your username and then your password.
remove the old gnome by typing apt purge gnome-shell
now all you need to do it type apt install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
restart your computer by typing reboot

that is the two ways I know how to fix it. Feel free to add more to this question if you know other ways to fix it.
